# Why does `ping -M do -s 8000` still work between hosts with different MTU values?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I have two hosts:

- alice (192.168.0.1, mtu 9000)
- bob (192.168.0.2, mtu 1500)

They are directly connected with a cat 6 cable, with no switch in between.

Why is it that I can still ping bob from alice, with a large packet size? E.g.:

```
$ ping -M do -s 8000 192.168.0.2
```

According to the manpage of `ping`, the `-M do` option is supposed to prohibit packet fragmentation.